# SQL 05 full-text query fails "Specified module could not be found."

Tags: sql-server-2005, full-text-search

I'm running SQL 2005 on Windows XP. I have a database table that has full text searching enabled. I was able to build and even re-build the index. However, when I try to query it like this:

```
Select * from fulltext_english
WHERE CONTAINS(page_data, 'causes')
```

I get this error:

Msg 7619, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The execution of a full-text query failed. "The specified module could not be found."

Did I miss something on the install? Is this a dll issue? I've googled and binged for days and can't find anything similar to this message.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you still get the error if you search for a word other than causes, a more concrete word like "car" for e.g. I am wondering if the word 'causes' is configured as a stopword in your database.

Comment: I tried several random words (car, rain, flower, purple, Obama) and got the same result.

Comment: More info: the ft catalog properties 'unique key count' and 'item count' are zero, and the catalog size is 0 MB. I tried rebuilding the catalog but no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be configuration setting issue.

When defining the column to index in the table, the "Language for Word Breaker" was set to null. I set it to "English" and the index started rebuilding on its own.